# How to not show Jquery Tooltip if the email has not been taken

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm currently trying to implement a feature to check if an email has already been taken when a first time user registers for my site. I'm trying to do this with AJAX and use the jQuery tooltip (http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/) plugin to display the message if the e-mail has in fact been taken.

I don't want to display any message if the e-mail is not taken and don't want the user to be aware of the fact that I'm checking their e-mail against the database, when they focus out of the e-mail input box. I only want to display a tooltip message if the e-mail has been taken and then make sure it dissapears if they provide a new unique e-mail address.

Here is my code thus far:
**register.php (where the form is)**

```
<div class="textboxfrm"><span class="label">Email<span style="color:#FF9000">* </span>              </span><span class="left"></span><span class="center"><input class="required validate-email" id="email" name="email" type="text" style="width:230px;" maxlength="50" />
</span>
<div class="tooltip_email"></div>
</div>
```

**register.js** (loaded on document.ready)

```
jQuery("span.center").tooltip({
    events: {
        span: 'dblclick, dblclick',
        input: 'blur, mouseout',
    },
    effect: "slide", 
    delay: 3000,
    onBeforeShow: function() {
        jQuery("#email").blur(function() { // when focus out

        email = jQuery('#email').attr('value');
        if (email.length > 1){
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "checkusername.php",
            data: "email=" + email,
            success: function(data) {
                jQuery(".tooltip_email").html(data);    
            } 
        }); //end ajax call
       }//end if email > 1
       else { jQuery("span.center").tooltip.hide(); }
        //jQuery(".tooltip_email").hide();
    });//end email blur
    //return false;
   } // end onBeforeShow function
}); //end span.center tooltip
```

Finally, **checkusername.php** (where the database is accessed)

```
<?php
$email = $_GET['email'];

// connection settings stored in file
include("connectionParameters.php");

$connection = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass)
    or die ("We're sorry, there seems to be an error. Please try again later.");

mysql_select_db($database);

$email = $_GET['email'];

mysql_select_db("testdatabase", $con);

$sql= sprintf("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE email='%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($email));

$result = mysql_query($sql);

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$taken = $row['email'];

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
    echo "<p>This email belongs to a registered user. Please provide a different email address, or visit <a href='forgot_pass.php'>this</a> page to retrieve your password.</p>";
}
else if(mysql_num_rows($result) < 1) { exit(); }
mysql_close($con);

?>
```

To make the question a little clearer, the checking of the email is working correctly and I'm seeing the message if an email is taken via the tooltip. However, I'm also seeing the tooltip with no message if I hover over "span.center" or if I change the email to a valid one or If the email is greater than 2 characters. My problem is that I don't want to see the tooltip box **at all** under any of those scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a basic check of the returned data in the AJAX response handler:

```
if (data != '') {
    jQuery(".tooltip_email").html(data);    
}
```

and only output your "error" message from the PHP script if the email's actually taken. However, considering doing something a little more fancy, using a JSON data structure, which gives you far more flexibility:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $data = array('error' => true, 'message' => 'Email already taken';
} else {
    $data = array('error' => false, 'message' => 'Everything A-OK';
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

which you then handle in JS with:

```
if (data.error) {
    jQuery(".tooltip_email").html(data.message);    
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marc, I'll give that a try. 

However, if the email is not taken and I get to the else clause in the php if statement you provided, won't the message display stating "Everything A-OK"?

Also, do I have to provide a dataType: "json", to my AJAX call now?

Comment: That's why you have the `if()` check, and only display the tooltip IF there's something that needs displaying. Your code displays everything, always.

Comment: I tried your implementation and for some reason, I'm still seeing the jQuery tooltip popup when I hover over "span.input", without any data.message. If it sees that the checkusername.php returned "data.error" then it correctly displays the message, but it displays it even if the user changes the email to one that is not taken. Is there a way to refresh the javascript so it outputs the message every time the field is changed?

I'm not sure if it's my javascript or something I'm overlooking with the jQuery tooltip plugin. 

Thanks for the help thus far, but any ideas on this?

Comment: maybe force the tooltip to hide, in case it was previously displayed:`if data.error { show tooltip } else { hide tooltip }` kinda thing.

Comment: Hmm, should I wrap everything in the ajax call or in the "if data.error"? Because right now I'm wrapping everything in the tooltip() call and using AJAX in the "onBeforeShow" action of the tooltip.

Comment: Skip the onbefore show entirely, and just make the blur handler do the ajax request, THEN display the tooltip if need be.

Comment: Hey Marc, I voted your answer as the correct one because I switched over to using JSON. Your suggestion of wrapping everything in the blur handler was a good one and I actually used jQUery("element").css("display","none"); to hide the tooltip when it is not needed, instead of the show and hide methods. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: How would I stop the user from registering if they fill out every other field and without leaving the email field click the submit button? I just checked, and the form submits successfully with the dupe email address in this case. Can I somehow call 2 functions on the submit buttons onSubmit action?

Comment: `onSubmit="function1(); function2(); etc..."` would work, but consider putting it all into a separate new function so it's easy to abort the submit if something's not right.